# qemu installation in ubuntu ? shows some error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, qemu

I'm installed qemu in my ubuntu 12.04, in both ways [through source and from the software center in ubuntu] it shows same error. It does not pop up the qemu window. when i'm given a dummy filesystem,kernel,initrd, it simply shows some "VNC SERVER listening 127.0.0.1" screen and hangs no more response. Please give me the installation steps and needful libraries to run simple qemu for x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include `SDL` support to QEMU and add option `-sdl` to run it. VNC is by default probably means you don't have SDL devel lib. Install `libsdl-dev` with apt.

Comment: I mean `libsdl-dev` is necessary only when you compile QEMU from src yourself.